# sshpass splitting the password as two strings seperated by the character "&" in password

Tags: escape-characters, special-characters, jenkins, sshpass

I have a password variable PASS whose value is abc123&zxcv456 When I try to do SSH in jenkins using the password variable like below

```
sshpass -p ${PASS} ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no admin@100.200.3.4 'echo '${PASS}' | sudo -S docker stats --no-stream'
```

only the string before special character & is interpreted and the value of the variable PASS is read as abc123, any help to get around this?

PS I have tried using escape character "${PASS}" but no progress there .

Comment: In general a variable expanded locally and embedded in shell code to be executed by *another* shell can inject code. It's a non-trivial task to quote it right for the other shell. In this particular case the second `${PASS}`, after being expanded locally, gets embedded in the shell code to be executed on the remote side. There unquoted `&` is special. Ask yourself what the remote shell gets as code. I know few tricks in shells to quote right to avoid further interpretation; but I don't know Jenkins, I guess "in jenkins" is relevant, so no answer from me. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In Jenkins Pipeline, use the built-in credentials store and the [`sshAgent` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-agent/) to pass your SSH username/password to an ssh command.

There is a similar option in the job configuration GUI for Freestyle jobs.

Answer (score -1):

Define the password as

```
abc123\&zxcv456
```

Comment: This should not be necessary with correct quoting.

Comment: Apparently it isn't working with the current quoting.

Comment: That's obvious.  In fact `$PASS` is used _unquoted_, twice. See also Kamil's comment on the question itself.

Comment: I did try both ways quoting $PASS and defining password with escape character, issue seems to be with jenkins shell.